# Composer init command - Change default author name

Tags: php, composer-php

This is for more understanding of the inner work of Composer and I didn't find any answer elsewhere on the Internet or even Composer documentation.

When creating my `composer.json` file, I usually go with command line `composer init`, the `package` name is defaulted to my pc name and `vendor` to the current folder name. All is great.

Now on `author`, it automatically uses `my name <my Hotmail Account>`. As far as I know those information are not stored anywhere on my computer. I only have one profile/user (only have one user which is admin with no detail of email or real name).

I have GitHub installed, PHP, Ruby on Rails, XAMPP and don't have any Windows Live installed.

Now, where does it take those information from? My best guess is from GitHub info, which is the only thing that have those info, but I would like to confirm it.

Comment: my guess would be the logged in user of the cli running the create command?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, Composer takes the information from your Git configuration.

The following two lines of the Composer 1.3 source code on GitHub clearly show this:

- https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.3.0/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php#L240
- https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.3.0/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php#L497

**Line 240:**

```php
        if (null === $author = $input->getOption('author')) {
            if (isset($git['user.name']) && isset($git['user.email'])) {
                $author = sprintf('%s <%s>', $git['user.name'], $git['user.email']);
            }
        }
```